# Bracets, parenthesis autocomplete in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

Could someone please tell me how I can disable parenthesis autocomplete in NetBeans in 6.9.1. I cannot find settings for that.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brackets go to `Tools > Editor > Code completion`. Uncheck `Insert Closing brackets automatically`. Save.

For paranthesis...I don't know exactly what do you want to remove.